# Commerce Server 2007 OrderObjectMappings definition error

Tags: c#, asp.net, commerceserver2007

I am adding 3 new properties to my PurchaseOrder object and have gone through the process of adding the 3 new columns to the database table, updating the PurchaseOrder class and lastly the OrderObjectMappings.xml file to ensure the properties in the class map to the database correctly. It all appears correct but I get the following error when the mapping is attempted by commerce server:

> [MappedClassDataMismatchException: Table PurchaseOrders column
>   ConcessionOrder does not match expected column name MarshalledData
>   defined in the mapping.]
>   Microsoft.CommerceServer.Runtime.Orders.POLoader.LoadFromDataSetHelper(DataSet
>   dataSet, ClassInfo[] dependencyClassList, Int32 depClassListLen,
>   Hashtable[] depInstanceLookup, BinaryFormatter formatter, String
>   filter) +3406
>   Microsoft.CommerceServer.Runtime.Orders.POLoader.LoadFromDataSet(DataSet
>   dataSet, OrderGroupCollection ogColl) +1080
>   Microsoft.CommerceServer.Runtime.Orders.POLoader.LoadSearchSet(Guid
>   searchSetId, OrderGroupCollection ogc) +388
>   Microsoft.CommerceServer.Runtime.Orders.POLoader.Load(String
>   storedProcName, ListDictionary sqlParameters) +458
>   Microsoft.CommerceServer.Runtime.Orders.OrderContext.GetPurchaseOrdersForUser(Guid
>   userId) +352

ConcessionOrder is one of my new properties and appears correctly mapped in the xml file. Does anyone know of any obvious reason why this could be happening, something I have missed perhaps, another setting elsewhere?

Cheers,
John

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that you updated all locations in the OrderObjectMappings.xml

For example in this node

```
<ClassTableMap Class="PurchaseOrder" Table="PurchaseOrders">
```

one of the

```
<PropertyMap ... />
```

lines might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The **StorageMap** root element of the **OrderObjectMapping.xml** file has 3 child elements that handle mappings between tables and classes and between table columns and class properties.

### TABLES NODE

The **Tables** element maps each child **Table** element to a physical database table. Each child **Column** element is mapped to a physical database field.

### CLASSES NODE

The **Classes** element contains a child **Class** element that corresponds to each Commerce Server 2007 API class. The out of the box properties and your extensions to the properties list exist as child **Property** elements.

### MAPPINGS NODE

The **Mappings** element is responsible for mapping each child **Table** element in the **Tables** element to a child **Class** element of the **Classes** element. This element drives the mapping of a physical database table and its columns to the class and child properties of that class.

In order to extend the PurchaseOrder setup in the OrderObjectMapping.xml file to include your new "**ConcessionOrder**" property, your file would need to contain modifications to the **Tables**, **Classes** and **Mappings** elements as shown below.

NOTE: I have assumed that you are using a bit field to model the boolean ConcessionOrder property...

[image]